# Rails 7 css assets are not working in production, need help understanding how the asset pipeline works without webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-7

Trying out rails 7, with tailwind and postcss.

I have a few stylesheets in assets/stylesheets, which I import through a file called imports.css in the same folder.

```
//imports.css
@import stylesheet1.css;
@import stylesheet2.css;
```

I then import that file in application.html.erb with the following:

```
//application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "imports", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

On development everything works fine as intended, meshes well with tailwind. Importing works fine due to postcss. However on production (nginx, puma) it tries to pull in those files and fails. For every stylesheet I have, i see in the browser console:

GET https://mywebsite.com/assets/style/stylesheet1.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I am trying to shift my brain over from webpacker in rails 6, not sure what I need to do here... some thoughts:

1. Do i need to set it up so that the stylesheets get copied over to the public/assets folder or something? Is there a setting to do that in production.rb? (I feel like rails by default should be already doing this)
2. Do I need to be manually precompiling these assets on deployment?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I had a similar issue. It could be that in `production.rb`you're not serving static files (I can see you are trying to access the static files directly from the broswer, not the precompiled ones.

You can do it through environment variables in production.rb, `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`

Answer (score 3):

@stellenberger was right and deserves the credit. In my case their solution of enabling the public file server for static assets fixed this issue for me and immediately started serving the css assets from public. I was already precompiling, they just weren't being served. I am using Rails docker containers on an EC2 in AWS behind an ALB, and there is no local NGINX so the default assumed is not correct for my scenario and needed to be changed.

The `config/environments/production.rb` file already provides an environment variable that will turn on the public server if present, called `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES` so all you need to do is set that environment variable in your build or deploy process. Since it is a presence check, any value will be truthy as the var existence is all that is checked.

Alternatively, you could also set

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

in the file instead of using the ENV var, but generally the ENV vars are better than hard-coded configs.

In my case, I changed the default to

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV.fetch("RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES") { true }
```

that way my default is true and enabled without setting the var, but I can still use the var to disable it if desired.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to be manually precompiling these assets on deployment?

Yes. Since you're not using a Node workflow now, instead relying on Sprockets and assets directly, you need the precompile step in Production.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the environment variables `RAILS_ENV=production` and `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true` did the job for me (with Rails 7.0.4).